# Математические функции и алгоритмы

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ли алгоритмы вычисления значений математических функций (в частности, тригонометрических, логарифмических и экспоненциальных) более простые с точки зрения вычислительной сложности, нежели разложение в [ряд Тейлора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)?

Для вычисления значения с помощью ряда Тейлора как известно требуется ряд манипуляций с факториалами и возведениями в степень и весьма немаленькое число итераций для получения приемлемой точности.

Comment: таблицы+аппроксимация.

Comment: Было тут уже [обсуждение такой темы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/140016/%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-java-math-sin)

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, мысль про аппроксимацию почему-то вылетела из головы

Comment: тут вспомнил, когда то делал программу симуляции процессов, которая делала много расчетов, и синусы там были на первом месте. и на 800МГц процессоре все считалось за 50-60 секунд на итерацию. А преподаватель утверждал, что это слишком долго. Нужно хотя бы 5-10сек.

Я сделал таблицу синусов на 90 значений (всего 90!) и на одно значение всего байт. Часть расчетов пришлось переделать с этим учетом (синус менялся от 0 до 255). Сумарная погрешность системы возросла, но по моим оценкам была меньше 5%. Но расчеты велись всего пару секунд! и все было практически в реальном времени.
Таблицы - сила!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это целая наука. Этим занимается армия вычислителей (вернее занимались во времена атомных проектов в США и СССР). Сейчас это уже доведено до совершенства, отшлифовано и реализовано. Туча народа получили свои премии, звания имена на этом поприще. Мне посчастливилось быть лично знакомым с одним из мастодонтов той эпохи, а именно с [тов. Самарским А.А.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E0%EC%E0%F0%F1%EA%E8%E9%2C_%C0%EB%E5%EA%F1%E0%ED%E4%F0_%C0%ED%E4%F0%E5%E5%E2%E8%F7)

В общем и целом, для вычисления матфункций в основном используются ортогональные полиномы: Чебышев, Якоби и проч. Тейлор здесь не катит.

Comment: спасибо. Познавательно